# Dynamic bar plot from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, pgfmath, tikz-calc

I need to draw a bar chart based on the data from the file. The data looks something like this

```
\begin{filecontents*}{tls.dat} 
    Name Abbreviation percentage
    Bod-Kin LS1 60 
Intraper LS2 40
Verb-Ling LS3 20 
Spat-Vis LS4 10
Natur LS5 5 
Interper LS6 0 
Mus LS7 0 
Log-Math LS8 0
\end{filecontents*}
```

Bar chart involves only rows that have percentage value higher than 0, and it needs to look something like this.

[image]

So far I have managed to read the data, have it sorted based on the percentage and I can draw the dynamic bar graphs manually, but I can't scale the length of the bar based on the top values from data.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=43px,bottom=45.4px,right=46px,top=35px]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{filecontents*}{tls.dat} 
    Name Abbreviation percentage
    Bod-Kin LS1 60 
    Intraper LS2 40
    Verb-Ling LS3 20 
    Spat-Vis LS4 10
    Natur LS5 5 
    Interper LS6 0 
    Mus LS7 0 
    Log-Math LS8 0
\end{filecontents*}

\definecolor{backgroundgray}{HTML}{EDEDED}
\definecolor{hashc}{HTML}{00A3E5}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=35px, left=44px, right=43.7px,bottom=60.4px}
\pagecolor{backgroundgray}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

\newcounter{mya}

%% calculate how many attributes have positive value

\pgfplotstableread[columns={Name,Abbreviation,percentage}]{tls.dat}\datatableA
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={percentage}, sort cmp=int >]{\datatablesorted}{\datatableA}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatablesorted} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\TotalRows}{\pgfplotsretval} 
 \foreach \k in {0,...,\RowsInTable}{
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(\pgfplotsretval)}
 \ifnum\itest=1
\stepcounter{mya}
\fi}


\noindent\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
\begin{minipage}[t][]{230px}
\vspace*{15px}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{16px}{30px}\color{gray}\textsl{TLS}
\end{center}
\addtocounter{mya}{-1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% draw names of bar plot
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \def\maxlength{\pgfplotsretval}

 \foreach \k in {0,...,\value{mya}}{
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(\pgfplotsretval)}
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Abbreviation}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \node at (0,-\k) {\fontsize{12px}{16px}\selectfont\color{gray}\pgfplotsretval};

 %draw bar plots
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\curlength{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfmathsetmacro\lengthpernodeA{0.9*\curlength / \maxlength}
 \fill [hashc] (0.5,-\k-0.25) rectangle (\lengthpernodeA\textwidth,0.25-\k);
 }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

}

\end{document}
```

MWE gives me this

[image]

Comment: Your code works beautifully if you replace `\def\maxlength{\pgfplotsretval}` by `\edef\maxlength{\pgfplotsretval}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for underestimating the question! Let me first explain what went wrong in your code. When you say `\def\maxlength{\pgfplotsretval}` then `\maxlength` will be updated when you update `\pgfplotsretval`. However, if you expand the value, i.e. use `\edef\maxlength{\pgfplotsretval}` (no, `e` does not stand for egreg ;-) then it works. This is what the following code does, in which I stripped off packages that are not needed here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=43px,bottom=45.4px,right=46px,top=35px]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{tls.dat} 
    Name Abbreviation percentage
    Bod-Kin LS1 60 
    Intraper LS2 40
    Verb-Ling LS3 20 
    Spat-Vis LS4 10
    Natur LS5 5 
    Interper LS6 0 
    Mus LS7 0 
    Log-Math LS8 0
\end{filecontents*}

\definecolor{backgroundgray}{HTML}{EDEDED}
\definecolor{hashc}{HTML}{00A3E5}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=35px, left=44px, right=43.7px,bottom=60.4px}
\pagecolor{backgroundgray}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

\newcounter{mya}

%% calculate how many attributes have positive value

\pgfplotstableread[columns={Name,Abbreviation,percentage}]{tls.dat}\datatableA
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={percentage}, sort cmp=int >]{\datatablesorted}{\datatableA}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatablesorted} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\TotalRows}{\pgfplotsretval} 
 \foreach \k in {0,...,\RowsInTable}{
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(\pgfplotsretval)}
 \ifnum\itest=1
\stepcounter{mya}
\fi}


\noindent\fcolorbox{white}{white}{
\begin{minipage}[t][]{230px}
\vspace*{15px}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{16px}{30px}\color{gray}\textsl{TLS}
\end{center}
\addtocounter{mya}{-1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%% draw names of bar plot
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \edef\maxlength{\pgfplotsretval} % <----
 \foreach \k in {0,...,\value{mya}}{
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(\pgfplotsretval)}
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Abbreviation}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \node at (0,-\k) {\fontsize{12px}{16px}\selectfont\color{gray}\pgfplotsretval};

 %draw bar plots
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \edef\curlength{\pgfplotsretval}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\lengthpernodeA{(0.9*\curlength /\maxlength)}
 \fill [hashc] (0.5,-\k-0.25) rectangle (\lengthpernodeA\textwidth,0.25-\k);
 }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an alternative using an xbar plot of pgfplots. It might be easier to customize.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{tls.dat} 
Name Abbreviation percentage
Bod-Kin LS1 60 
Intraper LS2 40
Verb-Ling LS3 20 
Spat-Vis LS4 10
Natur LS5 5 
Interper LS6 0 
Mus LS7 0 
Log-Math LS8 0
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\definecolor{backgroundgray}{HTML}{EDEDED}
\definecolor{hashc}{HTML}{00A3E5}
\newcounter{mya}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[columns={Name,Abbreviation,percentage}]{tls.dat}\datatableA
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={percentage}, sort cmp=int <]{\datatablesorted}{\datatableA}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatablesorted} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\TotalRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
\setcounter{mya}{0} 
\foreach \k in {0,...,\RowsInTable}{
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{percentage}\of{\datatablesorted}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(\pgfplotsretval>0,1,0)}
\ifnum\itest=1
 \typeout{\k,\pgfplotsretval}
 \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{Abbreviation}\of{\datatablesorted}
 \typeout{\pgfplotsretval}
 \ifnum\number\value{mya}=0
 \xdef\LstAbbr{"\pgfplotsretval"}
 \else
 \xdef\LstAbbr{\LstAbbr,"\pgfplotsretval"}
 \fi
 \stepcounter{mya}
\fi}
\begin{axis}[xbar,hide axis,clip=false]
    \addplot [draw=none,fill=hashc,
     y filter/.expression={
        x<=0 ? nan : y
    }] table[y expr=\coordindex,x=percentage] {\datatablesorted};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\number\value{mya}}{
    \node[left,gray] at (axis cs:0,#1-\number\value{mya}+\RowsInTable){\pgfmathparse{{\LstAbbr}[#1-1]}\pgfmathresult};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A nontrivial test with different assignments:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{tls.dat} 
Name Abbreviation percentage
Bod-Kin LS1 60 
Intraper LS3 40
Verb-Ling LS4 20 
Spat-Vis LS2 10
Natur LS5 5 
Interper LS6 0 
Mus LS7 0 
Log-Math LS8 0
\end{filecontents*}
```

leads to

[image]

Comment: tls.dat is not sorted.. it will be added manually, and I need to have only rows that have values in chart.. not every single one.. this is why I am sorting data in Latex.. e.g. if I change LS8 to 70 and everything else stays the same, then I wil have empty bar plots.. ...

Comment: @Almic7 Yes, sorry. I updated my answer.